# Android SQLite mult thread issue

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, aidl

I'll try be clear but if more details about code is needed I can provide it.

We have an app ABC that provide access do Db through aidl binders. The client app XYZ perform IPC calls to DAO implementation on the ABC app. Commands like select, insert, update and delete works very well but when we call these commands under a transaction we got problem.

Basically the first call to SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction() - through one binder object - a new transaction on the SQLite is set and the method SQLiteDatabase.inTransaction() returns true. Then when we call anyDAO.insert(...) check the inTransaction() returns false.

We found that the first call (beginTransaction) was executed in the service in Thread TID #1 and the second (insert) in another thread TID #2. Change the code (only to do a test) to do beginTransaction and insert in a single IPC call worked, but we need to call separate.

Question: is SQLite ready to deal transaction and SQL commands in different threads?

Comment: i already gave you a working code of redirecting every AIDL call to a specified thread, so why dont you use it?

Comment: @pskink We're working in our code. But because time is running, we set another developer working in some different approaches and we got the answers in the end of the day: Your code drove us to a working solution (we'll post the results in the other question). Also we found that in SQLite when you starts a Transacion in a thread you must perform the other commands in the same thread, otherwise you have no transaction.

Answer (score 0):

From the [SQL documentation](http://sqlite.org/whentouse.html):

> SQLite supports an unlimited number of simultaneous readers, but it will only allow one writer at any instant in time. For many situations, this is not a problem. Writer queue up. Each application does its database work quickly and moves on, and no lock lasts for more than a few dozen milliseconds. But there are some applications that require more concurrency, and those applications may need to seek a different solution.

The reason is that SQLite does not support “real” concurrency, like other Relational DBMS, even if the write operations are done on different data.

So, if your application requires many concurrent (updating) operations, you should think to use some other tool.